# Lines of Code in Eclipse PyDev Projects

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, metrics, pydev

I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck using the [Eclipse Metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net) Plugin with Projects that are not in Java (specifically I'm trying to generate code metrics for a couple of PyDev Projects).  I've read through the walk-through for the Metrics project but it indicates that I should be in the Java Perspective before accessing the Properties for my Project and that I should find a Metrics section.  I don't get that for my PyDev Projects regardless of which Perspective I have open.  Any suggestions or advice would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if it's doable to get the plugin to work with pydev projects, but if it's just the `lines-of-code` metric you are after, you could run this snippet in your project's root directory:

```
# prints recursive count of lines of python source code from current directory
# includes an ignore_list. also prints total sloc

import os
cur_path = os.getcwd()
ignore_set = set(["__init__.py", "count_sourcelines.py"])

loclist = []

for pydir, _, pyfiles in os.walk(cur_path):
    for pyfile in pyfiles:
        if pyfile.endswith(".py") and pyfile not in ignore_set:
            totalpath = os.path.join(pydir, pyfile)
            loclist.append( ( len(open(totalpath, "r").read().splitlines()),
                               totalpath.split(cur_path)[1]) )

for linenumbercount, filename in loclist: 
    print "%05d lines in %s" % (linenumbercount, filename)

print "\nTotal: %s lines (%s)" %(sum([x[0] for x in loclist]), cur_path)
```

Comment: That did what I needed it to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Linux...

Have you taken a look to [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)?

It produces pretty complete outputs, and accepts several of options:

```
borrajax@borrajax-linux:~/Documents/Projects/myProject$ cloc .
    1840 text files.
    1566 unique files.                                          
    9362 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.53  T=3.0 s (454.3 files/s, 81397.0 lines/s)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Javascript                      709          19190          17283          93862
Python                          333           6278           3399          38398
C                                86           3244           2303          17755
CSS                             122           1786           1592          16856
HTML                             55            784             51           8072
Bourne Shell                     14            651            280           6641
C/C++ Header                      6            301            293           1259
XML                               9              5              0           1153
PHP                               2             88            211            585
SQL                              19            200            127            576
Bourne Again Shell                2             57             15            494
make                              5             41             19            187
DOS Batch                         1             21              1            133
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           1363          32646          25574         185971
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is available in the Ubuntu repositories, as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix you can run the following from the terminal:

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs cat | egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]" | wc -l
```

If you want to not count comments, you need a better regular expression...